# Drawing a filled ellipse doesn't appear

Tags: c#

Trying to draw a pacman in c# using visual studio e started to drew the dots but i having some troubles i wrote this class to make the dots.

```
    public class draw : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
    public draw(int x, int y, int h, int c) {

        System.Drawing.SolidBrush brush1 = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(brush1, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, h, c));
        brush1.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And then in the form in a press a button and it should create some dots but nothing happens

```
draw d = new draw(100,100,100,100);
draw d1 = new draw(200,200,200,200);
```

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is not how you draw things. You handle the `Paint` event of your form or control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1 - This wa of drawing on a form or control is non-persistent; all drawing must either happen in a `Paint` event or be triggered from there. A good solution is to call the drawing code there and to hand down the `e.Graphics` of the `Paint` event as a parameter.

2 - You use `CreateGraphics`  and try to paint with that. The result would disappear anyway as soon as you e.g. minimze your window and restore it. But in reality nothing get shown in the first place. Why? Well, your draw blobs are an **inner class** and here the keyword `this`refers **not to the form** but **to the draw class**. So you create a Graphics for an invisible control (without a size and which is not part of the form) and, of course, nothing happens..

If you want to have Drawing items they should

- store their sizes, positions, states etc (in their constructor) and
- have a drawing method which you can call from the outside and which gets handed a Graphics object they then draw themselves on..
- they also should have a better name, like *Dot* or *PacDot* or the like..

Here is a minimal version:

```
// a list of all PacDots:
public List<PacDot> theDots = new List<PacDot>();

public class PacDot : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
    public PacDot(int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        Left = x; Top = y; Width = w; Height = h; 
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics G)
    {
      G.FillEllipse(Brushes.Brown, 
        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Left, Top, Width,  Height));
    }
}


private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (PacDot dot in theDots) dot.Draw(e.Graphics);
}

// a test button:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    theDots.Add(new PacDot(30, 10, 5, 5));
    theDots.Add(new PacDot(30, 15, 5, 5));
    theDots.Add(new PacDot(15, 10, 5, 5));
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

PS: Since your draw class is indeed a Control descendent you could also add them to the Form with form1.Controls.Add(..); but they still will have to have a paint event, where they paint themselves..

Comment: The two problems you enumerate are actually the same problem. To draw persistently on a form/control, you need to handle the Paint event (or override OnPaint). In that event handler, you are passed a Graphics object to paint into. If you use CreateGraphics anywhere to paint, including in the Paint event handler, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Well, they came together and they'll go away together, but they are quite distinct errors. You can correct the second one by using a valid Graphics object but still miss out on the persistance issue. And you can use the Paint event and still use the `this` keyword wrongly inside an inner class..

Comment: I understood your answer and I have already done the  first  and third task but the second one (...drawing method...) I understood what you meant but I don't know which method to use and how to use it

Comment: I know that is the correct answer  but when i try to press the button nothing happens the form1_paint function is not being called i think

Comment: Did you just copy the code? The paint method call must also be added to the form's designer code. Doubleclicking the paint event in the properties will do that. Change the methodename to something else before you do that and then revert the change and delete the extra paint method stub. Also do study the 'code behind' in the Form1.Designer.cs!!